# Using shutdown instead of close for reuse of socket

Tags: sockets, vxworks

Using shutdown instead of close on a socket, is it possible to connect more then once on the socket?

```
s = socket(...);

for(;;)

{

     connect(s,...);

     //do some work

     shutdown (s, 2);

}
```

I'm testing it and getting errno 22. Is it supposed to work at all?

I want to have it this way since the application is doing the loop pretty fast and my sockets end up in the TIME_WAIT state holding alot of resourses.

I have tried SO_REUSEADDR but my sockets still end up in TIME_WAIT state..

Runnig vxworks 5.5.1

Comment: +1 interesting question. I've seen some strange differences in such behaviors on different operating systems, so a consistent 'works everywhere' answer would be great

Answer (score 0):

> Using shutdown instead of close on a socket, is it possible to connect more then once on the socket?

No. A TCP socket once connected cannot be re-connected.